# Grant access to box is needed everytime you revoke access from an app

Tags: authentication, box-api

I've updated my app to use the new Box V2 API instead of the old Box V1 API.

I have only one question left : After revoking access to an app ( http://developers.box.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Provision-Reject.png ), why is it required to grant access again after giving the password again?

Thanks for your answer in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When a user decides to revoke access to an application, they've basically decided that they don't trust that application to get to their Box content.  If they change their mind and want the application again, then the user should know what kinds on things your application can do.

The "grant access" screen is part of the OAuth2 specification, and is used by just about every website these days that lets applications get at user's accounts.  Android apps have a similar "grant" screen to say stuff like "This application wants to get at your address book, send emails, and ... only use it if you trust the application to do these things."